# Removing unwanted param from URL variations with REGEX

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

Is there possible to remove some unwanted param `unwanted` from URI in such way that final result should serve a proper uri?

The problem is that I have unwanted param in urls which I would like remove.
I tried but having problems with & and ? which should remain in place to not break the url

```
(unwanted=.*?)\\
```

https://regex101.com/r/CXEuqH/1

```
this is clean uri with no params - should remain unchanged 
(should be replaced to: /some-clean-part-of-url-012567):
22 sdff=\"a sdsdsd \" sfs f =\"/some-clean-part-of-url-012567\" saafa 42wsdf=\"sf  sdf sd 432\" asd


url with unwanted only and nothing else:
(should be replaced to: /url-with-unwanted-only):
asda ds3=\"afdaa \" asd ad a =\"/url-with-unwanted-only?unwanted=base-unwanted-value-0605\" aas asd =\"sddghf \"asdasd wsdf=\"sf  sdf sd 432\" a das 


uri with unwanted at the beginning and other one or more wanted params after it
(should be replaced to: /unwanted-at-the-beginning-plus-other-params-4560?wanted_params=wanted_values):
as da=\"hkgd\" a =\"/unwanted-at-the-beginning-plus-other-params-4560?unwanted=not-need-value-23333&wanted_param=wanted_value\" asd =\"sddd8963ghf \" asdasdasd 


uri with unwanted at the end
(should be: unwanted-at-the-end-789870?wanted_param=wanted_value):
asda asd =\"sddwsd333ghf \"asdasdsd as as =\"/unwanted-at-the-end-789870?wanted_param=wanted_value&unwanted=unwanted-value-1-1s\" ad fd df sasd =\"sfe352ddghf \" asdasddf 


uri with unwanted in the middle
(should be: /unwanted-in-the-middle-38642?wanted_param=wanted_value&param_wanted=111):
as asd =\"sfe352ddghf \" as asd asd a =\"/unwanted-in-the-middle-38642?wanted_param=wanted_value&unwanted=some-unwanted-value0313&param_wanted=111\" ad sad asd a asd =\"sfe352ddghf \" as
```

I tried but having problems with & and ? which should remain in place to not break the url

Final result should be a proper uri without unnecessary "&" and "?" at the end

Comment: What would be desired output from these examples? If you remowe "?" from substitution than "?" and "&" remain in place.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/1F8hbh/1

Comment: The desired matches are given for every example in the question. Voting to reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
(?<=[?&])unwanted=[^&?=\s\\"]*&?
```

The pattern matches:

- `(?<=[?&])` Positive lookbehind, assert what is directly to the left is either `?` or `&`
- `unwanted=` Match literally
- `[^&?=\s\\"]*` Repeat 0+ times matching any character except for the listed in the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)
- `&?` Match an optional ampersand

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/el47s3/1)